# Can i restrict ip ranges for internet gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to restrict internet gateway from 0.0.0.0/0 to why own IP address i.e 119.11.111.11/32. 
I want to restrict it to my IP address and then have the NAT Gateway to point to my IP address 119.11.122.11/32. 
The reason is to make it more secure and to make sure all requests are going to and from my IP address. 
I would like to know if anyone has done it and it still works. i have tried on my aws account and it has not worked. 
thank you

Comment: You can't do this as IGW (internte gateway) works at VPC level, and NAT gateway does not have security groups. You can however modify default network ACLs of your subnets and SGs of your instances or other interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want resources in an Amazon VPC to only be accessible to your own IP address, then you should configure the **Security Groups** on your resources.

By default, **security groups block all incoming traffic**. You can add **Inbound rules** to allow traffic from your IP address on the desired ports.

A **security group for a NAT Gateway** normally allows:

- No inbound traffic
- All outbound traffic (so that your private resources can access the Internet)